# How to Prevent Stack from Downloading Files

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I would like to be able to run Stack at work. It would have to run on a server which is not allowed to download any files. Only Ubuntu packages are allowed.

That's fine for me, since I can install Stack, GHC, and many libraries through Ubuntu. I've tested this out on my own Ubuntu machine, and this is what I had to do to make sure nothing was downloaded.

config.yaml

```
install-ghc: false
system-ghc: true

package-indices:
- name: NoDownloads
  download-prefix: localhost
  http: localhost
```

stack.yaml

```
resolver: ghc-8.0.2
packages:
- .
```

I set up this intentionally bad package index so Stack fails every time it tries to download a package that isn't already present on the server. This works, but feels like a ugly hack. Is there something better I can do?